# Ejecutar snmp desde mysql

Tags: mysql

¿Alguien podrá orientarme?

Intento ejecutar el comando `snmpwalk` (en servidor *linux*) desde la base de datos vía procedimiento para almacenar el resultado en una tabla:

```
snmpwalk -v 3 -u userAGPON17 -l authPriv -a SHA -A 'accesskey372' -x AES -X 'securitykey372' $Ip HUAWEI-XPON-MIB::hwGponDeviceOntSn
```

Gracias

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema o dificultad que tienes?

Comment: En mi servidor tengo un shell que hace el descubrimiento via snmp pero el inventario esta en un archivo csv, no quiero que depende de un archivo sino que se haga el descubrimiento (con snmp) y guardar el resultado en BD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No puedes ejecutar comandos desde la base de datos vía procedimiento. Puedes hacerlo desde el cliente MySQL añadiendo al principio los caracteres `\!`, por ejemplo `\! ls -a` pero no hay forma de ejecutarlos desde procedimiento para guardar directamente la salida estándar de los comandos. Simplemente ejecuta el comando desde un script de Bash, procesa la salida y guarda los datos haciendo consultas a la base de datos.

Comment: [Gracias por e apoyo]